# SQL simple query displaying error (CONTAINS function)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am trying to display all users with @devon.gov.uk address.

I am using following code:

```
SELECT * FROM `j25_users` WHERE `email` CONTAINS `@devon.gov.uk`
```

But I am getting following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONTAINS `@devon.gov.uk` LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

What could that indicate? SQL newbie here.

Comment: remove '', just j25_users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
SELECT * FROM `j25_users` WHERE `email` like '%@devon.gov.uk%'
```

Comment: This one ACTUALLY works, thank you very much! Will accept the answer once it lets me to do it.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM `j25_users` WHERE  CONTAINS (email,`@devon.gov.uk`)
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column '@devon.gov.uk' in 'where clause'

Comment: i just showed the corect `CONTAINS` syntax, to fix your problem remove quotes from table name, and change `'` to `"` on searche value

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your post phpmyadmin, so while the others have correctly provided the SQL way of doing this, I'll just point out that phpMyAdmin also gives you a graphical interface. From the "Search" tab, just scroll down to the "email" row and change the dropdown to `Like %...%` and put  `@devon.gov.uk` in the Value textbox. Then press Go.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM `j25_users` WHERE `email` LIKE `%@devon.gov.uk%`;
```

The problem was the backtick `. the above code should have been:

```
SELECT * FROM `j25_users` WHERE `email` LIKE '%@devon.gov.uk%';
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column '%@devon.gov.uk%' in 'where clause'